# Exit status ($?) of 148 upon Ctrl+Z

Tags: bash, shell, exit

I just [customized](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2013/01/14/whats-in-your-bash-prompt/) [my `.bashrc`](https://github.com/larsmans/dotfiles/blob/master/bashrc) to include the exit status of the last command, so I get fancy prompts like

```
☑ larsmans@host:~$
```

and I no longer have to re-run commands to see their exit status because I ran some other command in between. This uses `$?` to determine the exit status. However, I noticed that when a command is backgrounded with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, the shell also sets `$?`, so I keep seeing

```
[1]+  Stopped                 vim
☒ larsmans@host:~$ echo $?
148
```

Is this `148` a magic pseudo-exit status that I should check for?

Comment: I'm sure I'm not the only one guilty of just falling off the end of `main()` (and thus returning garbage as exit status). Others have turned out creative, returning anything from the number of items processed through the number of errors found to some perceived severity of the problems encountered. Several "original" Unix comands returned garbage as the exit status. `vi(1)` was a notorious example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found it just before hitting the "ask question" button. I looked at the [*ABS*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#EXITCODESREF), which suggests this is exit code 128 + signal `SIGTSTP` (even though no process exited). I then found out I inspect check the exit status using

```
kill -l $?
```

which reports `TSTP`, or "stop typed at tty", for 148.

Comment: You don't have to apologise for answering your own question :-) Such things are encouraged on the Stack Exchange network.