# Why does sending a process to background set $? to a non-zero value?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, background-process, exit-status

I've just noticed that sending a foreground process to background with <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> sets the `$?` variable to a non-zero value. Why is this the case?

This behavior is bothering me, because I wanted to have a terminal prompt which changes color when a command errors, and I did this following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16715681/5825294). However, this also means that if I'm working in Vim, everytime I send it to background with <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> the prompt changes color as if something went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(assuming `bash`)

Ctrl-Z does not send a process to background (as `bg %JOB_NUMBER` would), it *suspends* it. In order to do that a SIGSTP signal is sent to the process (you can do it yourself with `kill -SIGSTP PID`). SIGSTP is signal 20.

The return value you see is [148, or 128 + SIGSTP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62173/exit-status-of-148-upon-ctrlz).

So, you should change the code in that answer to check for that condition, it is always going to be 148.

Comment: It's not bash that sends the signal, it's the terminal driver in the kernel.

Comment: But this means that if a (badly designed?) program exits with code 148 upon error, I would have a false negative on the color of the prompt, right?

Comment: Programs will usually use errors below 128, but yes, a program could eventually exit with that code. Or have an error but return 0 anyway.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thanks, corrected.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis [Yes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590038/why-does-a-failed-cat-return-1-but-other-fails-return-2/590154#590154)

Comment: A program can use any 32 bit exit code and if you are on a `POSIX` compliant OS, the parent can retrieve this value using `waitid()`.  BTW: `SIGTSTP` is not in the list of signals with standardized number, so 148 does not mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seing is caused by using the antique `$?` that does not distinct between the cause of the death of a program and thus looses information.

`$?` contains either the low 8 bits from the `exit()` code of the program, `127` if the program could not be found, `126` if the file could be found but cannot be executed or `base` + `signal number` in case the program was terminated by a signal. `base` is a number that depends on the shell and is typically 128, 256 or 512.

If `$?` holds a number with the value 126, 127 or in the range 129..192, it is impossible to tell whether this is a code from `exit()` in the child, caused by a signal or caused by an `exec()` error.

Also note that the number in `$?` partly depends on the OS as only a few signals have granted standardized numbers. `SIGTSTP` is amongst the signals with unspecified numbers, there is still a way to get the signal name under the assumption that the number in`$?` is from a death via signal.

Check this example:

```
$ sleep 100^Z
$ echo $?
152
$ kill -l 152
TSTP
```

`kill -l` on the value from `$?` works on any `POSIX` shell, regardless of the value of `base` and the signal number used on the current OS for the named signal.

If you are using a userfriendly shell (e.g. `bosh`), there is more than `$?`. See this example:

```
$ sleep 100^Z
$ echo ${.sh.codename} ${.sh.termsig} ${.sh.status} $/ $?
KILLED TSTP 24 TSTP 152
$ (exit 1234567890)
$ echo ${.sh.codename} ${.sh.termsig} ${.sh.status} $/ $?
EXITED UNKNOWN 1234567890 1234567890 210
```

`${.sh.codename}` is the name for the reason of the child death from the list `EXITED KILLED DUMPED TRAPPED STOPPED CONTINUED NOEXEC NOTFOUND`.

`${.sh.termsig}` is the signal name related to the status code

`${.sh.status}` is the numeric status code.

The three variables above are `bosh` specific.

`$/` is a current `POSIX` proposal for a `$?` successor that contains a number when the program exited normally and text for signals or `NOEXEC` or `NOTFOUND`.

My example is using a 32 bit `exit()` code that only works on `POSIX` compliant operating systems. The value `210` is the result from the expression `1234567890 & 0xFF`.

Comment: Congratulations, one of the few posts from you that haven't been downvoted. cheers!.

Comment: Oooops, I spoke too quickly :-((